# Strategy for resolving dependency convergence errors with maven-enforcer-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3, spring-data-neo4j, maven-enforcer-plugin

I'm trying to use Neo4j's embedded `InProcess` server inside my application. At the same time, we are required to fix Maven `maven-enforcer-plugin` with `dependencyConvergence` rule enforced to keep dependencies clean and tidy.

Here's the project I'm talking about: https://github.com/k-kalinowski/GraphDatabase

Now, I decided to go with strategy of resolving convergence errors that looks like this: pick a version of the artifact which satisfies the most explicit dependencies and put it in the `dependencyManagement`.
After some cleaning in `dependencyManagement` section done, I was able to make the project pass the `dependencyConvergence` rule and finally compile it. While running tests, I get some runtime exceptions, which, I guess, are caused by me messing with the versions of the artifacts I picked as the right ones in `dependencyManagement` section.

Sample stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntityReferences(EntityGraphMapper.java:268)
at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:164)
at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.map(EntityGraphMapper.java:91)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:67)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:43)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.save(Neo4jSession.java:386)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepositoryImpl.save(GraphRepositoryImpl.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:475)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:432)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.save(Unknown Source)
at com.tr.springmvc.graph.repository.AdminApprovalRepositoryTest.canTakeAdminAction(AdminApprovalRepositoryTest.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
```

My question is, how does one find which dependency causes such runtime troubles? It doesn't even hint whether it's caused by :( What's the best strategy to employ when solving dependency version divergence in maven POMs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems my cleanup in modules was fine. After some investigation it like like a bug inside neo4j-ogm-1.1.3 `MetaData` matcher. By default, `@Relationship`'s annotated field type is generated in CamelCase while for `@RelationshipEntity` it's generated with underscore, so when Neo4j-ogm is trying to match relationship entity for given relationship field it can't find none. Quick fix is to provide matching type by hand 
E.g. change:

```
@Relationship
private AdminAction adminAction;
```

and

```
@RelationshipEntity
public class AdminAction {
```

to:

```
@Relationship(type = "ADMIN_ACTION")
private AdminAction adminAction;
```

and

```
@RelationshipEntity(type="ADMIN_ACTION")
public class AdminAction {
```